# How to convert HH:MM:SS to HH:MM

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I Have a problem. in my front-end UI  user will enter time something like **12:21** when i update in SQL server data base it is displaying as **12:21:23**
the time is storing in **DATETIME_PARAM** COLUMN  should i add convert or any other process is there to restrict the value ?

below code

```
UPDATE A SET 
                A.SYNCOPERATION = 'U',
                A.VERSION = A.VERSION + 1,
                A.SYNCVERSION = DBO.GetCountryDate(),
                A.PAR_VALUE3 = CASE @VALUE WHEN '' THEN NULL ELSE @VALUE END,
                A.DATETIME_PARAM = CASE @JITTIME WHEN '' THEN NULL ELSE @JITTIME END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),DateCol, 108)
```

ie, you can use the CONVERT function to restrict the time in HH:MM format in your database itself.(*Assuming that you dont need a **second** part in your datetime column*)

**EDIT:**

In your case you can put it like

```
A.DATETIME_PARAM = CASE @JITTIME WHEN '' THEN NULL ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),@JITTIME, 108)  END
```

Comment: where i need to add this?

Comment: @teja CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),@JITTIME, 108)

Comment: @Rahul : after adding this also same output iam getting    :  05:03:00  i want to display only hh:mm

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
....
A.PAR_VALUE3 = NULLIF(@VALUE, ''),
A.DATETIME_PARAM = LEFT(NULLIF(@JITTIME, ''), 5)
```

Don't forget to put a WHERE clause on that update